# rpmbuild %{dist} not defined on CentOS 5.5?

Tags: rpm, centos5, rpmbuild

I'm attempting to use the [`%{dist}`](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DistTag) tag in my RPM spec file to provide distribution-specific dependencies between Fedora Core (e.g. `fc12`), CentOS 5 (e.g. `el5`) and Amazon's Linux AMI:

```
Release: %_svn_revision%{?dist}
```

and

```
# Depencencies
%{?rhel:Requires: ...}
%{?fedora:Requires: ...}
```

Unfortunately, `%{dist}` doesn't appear to be defined in CentOS 5.5, and I haven't found a distribution-specific conditional that matches CentOS 5.5 (I thought `el5` would match, but doesn't appear to). [This](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3239) ticket reported the missing `%{dist}` in CentOS in 2008, but hasn't been updated since 2009.

How can I get `%{dist}` defined in CentOS and what conditional should I use to match CentOS 5? 
Can any RPM gurus point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The dist macros isn't defined on CentOS 5 because it isn't in `/etc/rpm/macros.disttag` - there is a RPM named `buildsys-macros-rhel` that provides it, or `buildsys-macros` on fedora, but for some reason it is not repackaged by Centos.

Option 1) Download and install fedora build-macros from [here](http://buildsys.fedoraproject.org/buildgroups/rhel5/i386/)

Option 2) invoke rpmbuild --define 'dist .el5' every time

Option 3) Manually edit /etc/rpm/macros.disttag to add macro definitions for rhel (5) and dist (.el5).

You can then use conditionals like this in your spec file:

```
%if 0%{?rhel}  == 5
%{Requires: foo}
%endif
```

Comment: build-macros for el5 did the trick. Thank you for a great answer.

Comment: Note that as of CentOS 5.7, `buildsys-macros` is available in the distribution. See [Redhat Advisory](http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHEA-2011-0985.html) as well as [Redhat Bug 613985](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=613985)

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to call the script within your own macro in the spec file:

```
%define distribution        %(/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/dist.sh --distnum)
```

which calls a script which is part of the config rpm (redhat-rpm-config). You can also insure that this script is there by including:

```
BuildRequires:              redhat-rpm-config
```

and then do the same conditional as ggiroux has defined:

```
%if %{distribution} == 5
    Requires:                   glibc.i686, libXext.i386, libXtst.i386
%else
    Requires:                   glibc.i686, libXext.i686, libXtst.i686
%endif
```